# kivy button calls method of another class

Tags: python, kivy

I have a simple problem which keeps me busy in the last days.

In Kivy I have two Windows.
FirstWindow has a method update(), which is triggered by a button press.
On SecondWindow I have only one button, which sends me back to FirsWindow, but I want it to trigger the update() method from FirstWindow and change the label, just like the "update label" button does on FirstWindow, without previously pressing the "update label" button.

Any help, please?

file.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class FirstWindow(Screen):

    my_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    my_label = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update(self):
        self.my_label.text = 'UPDATED'


class SecondWindow(Screen):

    def go_first(self):
        FirstWindow().update()


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('my_test.kv')


MyTestApp().run()
```

my_test.kv

```
WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<FirstWindow>:
    name: "first"
    my_label: my_label_id

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: my_label_id
            text:"Label"
            font_size:self.width / 5
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Button:
                text: "next screen"
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'second'
            Button:
                text: "update label"
                on_press: root.update()

<SecondWindow>:
    name:"second"
    Button:
        text: "go back and update"
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'first'
            root.go_first()
```

[image]

I think critical is this method, whitch needs to be remake, but I have no idea how

```
    def go_first(self):
        FirstWindow().update()
```

Comment: http://inclem.net/2019/06/20/kivy/widget_interactions_between_python_and_kv/

Comment: using `FirstWindow()` in line `FirstWindow().update()` you create new instance of window `FirstWindow` but it doesn't give access to first/original instance of `FirstWindow`. Both windows are in the same `WindowManager` so probably in `SecondWindow` you could use `self.parent` to access `WindowManager` and `self.parent.FirstWindow` to access other window.

Comment: I modify the method as this

    def go_first(self):
        self.parent.FirstWindow.update()

but it still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly access another screen which is defined as another class. First, you have to access the ScreenManager i.e. Parent class and then from it get the screen `FirstScreen`
So the `go_first` function in your code will look like this:

```
def go_first(self):
    self.parent.get_screen('first').update()
```

EDIT:
Here's full code:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class FirstWindow(Screen):

    my_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    my_label = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update(self):
        self.my_label.text = 'UPDATED'


class SecondWindow(Screen):

    def go_first(self):
        self.parent.get_screen('first').update()


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('my.kv')


MyTestApp().run()
```

my.kv:

```
WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<FirstWindow>:
    name: "first"
    my_label: my_label_id

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: my_label_id
            text:"Label"
            font_size:self.width / 5
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Button:
                text: "next screen"
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'second'
            Button:
                text: "update label"
                on_press: root.update()

<SecondWindow>:
    name:"second"
    Button:
        text: "go back and update"
        on_press:
            root.manager.current = 'first'
            root.go_first()
```

Comment: It's working fine for me. What error are you getting? and which version of kivy are you using

Comment: Python 3.9, Kivy 2.0.0, coding in IntelliJ

Comment: and what error are you getting? have you changed code after posting it here? coz its working fine for me, [see](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P9ToawsqI_zNsBW1TSDTuvi-K-UvW2hW/view?usp=sharing). Also, i have posted full code in answer try that once.

Comment: It works now! God bless you and your family. You saved my life as programmer.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, then you might consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so other people see it too :)